# How can I create an input mask for MM/YY

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to create a React Native input component for a credit card expiration date.

I believe I should input mask should be in the format for MM/YY. I'm not sure about autofill with `autoCompleteType="cc-exp"` and `textContentType="creditCardNumber"`.

How can this be done without a library and only javascript/typescript?

**InputCreditCardExpirationDate.tsx**

```
  // React Hooks: State
  const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('');

  const formatMMY = (string: string): string => {
    // HOW?
  };

  // On Change
  const onChange = (text: string): void => {
    // MM/YY
    text = formatMMY(text);

    if (text.length >= 1) {
      // Set State
      setValue(text);

      // Props: On Change Text
      onChangeText(text);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Input
      value={value}
      placeholder={placeholder || 'Expires'}
      label={label ? label : 'Expires'}
      keyboardType="numeric"
      onChangeText={onChange}
      autoCompleteType="cc-exp" // Android Only
      textContentType="creditCardNumber" // iOS Only
      maxLength={7}
      darkMode={darkMode || false}
    />
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a library "react-native-masked-text"

import { TextInputMask } from 'react-native-masked-text'

...

```
 <TextInputMask
 placeholder="mm / yy"
 style={styles.inputLine} 
 placeholderTextColor="#4D4D4D" 
 refInput={ref =>{setExDateRef(ref)}}
 includeRawValueInChangeText={true}
 onChangeText={(maskedText) => { setCardExpiry(maskedText); }}
 value={cardExpiry} 
 type={'custom'}
 options={{mask: '99/99'}}
 keyboardType={'numeric'}
 onSubmitEditing={() => {cvvRef.focus() }}
 returnKeyType="next"
  />
```